# Как организовать коллекцию с возможностью добавления как в начало, так и в конец?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Программирую мессенжер на c# c mvvm.У меня есть большая коллекция сообщений пользователя. По открытии окна с перепиской с определенным человеком у меня вызывается метод

```
private void MoreMessages()
   {   
       builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids);
       Datas.offset += 200;

   }
```

который из общей массы сообщений выбирает и добавляет в коллекцию **builder.ConcreteDialogList** только сообщения,принадлежащие переписке с определенным пользователем.

Для возможности биндинга, я приравнял ссылки на объявленную внутри vm данного окна **ReadyCollection = builder.ConcreteListDialog;** в конструкторе этого окна.

**Datas.offset += 200;** -это статическая переменная- смещение, необходимое для подгрузки новой партии сообщений. Она сначала равна 0 и  используется в **builder.ConcreateDialogCreater(ids);** В

Так вот, не могу понять  каким образом объявить ReadyCollection , чтобы В нее можно было добавлять элементы как сначала, так и с конца относительно уже лежащих в ней элементов.

**Для чего это нужно?** Сначала я сделал так, что эта коллекция заполняется таким образом:  пачка сообщений в ней уже лежит и все, сообщения расположены от самых старых в начале коллекции до самых новых в конце. И ,когда пользователь отправляет сообщение - оно добавляется в самый конец, как и вновь пришедшие сообщения.

Но сейчас я сделал кнопку "Больше сообщений", которая вызывает метод MoreMessages() и увеличивает смещение, и , логично, что эти сообщения нужно добавлять еще выше ,чем те, которые уже есть в ней. Но как это сделать, ведь отрицательных индексов у нас нет , а Insert(0)-выходит что постоянно нужно сдвигать все большую и большую группу сообщений.При текущей ситуации сообщения добавляются в конец коллекции, что нарушает последовательность переписки.

Какой есть выход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` вам для этих целей вполне подойдёт.

Для добавления в конец списка можно использовать `List<T>.Add(T value)` или `.AddRange(T[] Values)` если добавляете массив.

А для добавления в начало списка можно использовать `List<T>.Insert(int index, T Value)` где `index` указываете равным 0. Если добавляете сразу массив-используйте `InsertRange` аналогично указывая в нём индекс вставки равным 0.

Comment: Спасибо, да этот вариант я сейчас и использую. Но не костыль ли это?Ведь вся коллекция двигается вниз при добавлении одного элемента. Или все же это нормально?
InsertRange не используется для ObservableCollection, мне же нужно ее отображать

Comment: Ну может и костыль... Но исходя из постановки вопроса вам нужен двунаправленный список. Обычный лист реализует необходимую функциональность так сказать "из коробки" 
Как вариант можете использовать LinkedList<T>. Это как раз таки двунаправленный список. Но у него нет возможности вставки сразу массива, эту функциональность придётся реализовывать самостоятельно